# How does wavg work in depth using a vectorised approach?

Tags: kdb

The objective of the snippet below is to evaluate weighted mid for n levels of an order book. The  code snippet is from the book Machine Learning and Big Data with kdb+/q (2020 Wiley).

```
n:10;
quote: ([] sym: n?`A`B; time: asc n?0t; bid1: n?10f; bidSize1: n?100 );
update bid2: 0 | bid1 - .1 * n ? 10, bidSize2: n?100, ask1: bid1 + .2 * n ? 10, askSize1: n?100 from quote;
update ask2: ask1 + .1 * n ? 10, askSize2: n?100 from `quote;
select sym,time, wmid: ( bidSize1; bidSize2; askSize1; askSize2 ) wavg (bid1; bid2; ask1; ask2) from quote
```

I would like to understand a generic rule for how the wavg method works in-depth for lists of vectors. Could you please help me? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are docs here on wavg https://code.kx.com/q/ref/avg/#wavg.

From these docs we can see that calling wavg is the equivalent to the function `{(sum x*y)%sum x}`

Using your example:

```
q)res1:select sym,time, wmid: ( bidSize1; bidSize2; askSize1; askSize2 ) wavg (bid1; bid2; ask1; ask2) from quote;
q)res2:select sym,time, wmid:{(sum x*y)%sum x} [( bidSize1; bidSize2; askSize1; askSize2 );(bid1; bid2; ask1; ask2)] from quote;
q)res1 ~ res2
1b
```

So in the case of your example we multiply bidSize1*bid, bidSize2*bid2, etc. , sum this result, then divide by the sums of our sizes e.g. `(bidSize1[0]+ bidSize2[0] + askSize1[0] + askSize2[0];(bidSize1[1]+ bidSize2[1] + askSize1[1] + askSize2[1]; etc...)`

I'm not sure if there is a more a general way of describing this but the above may help understand the nuts and bolts of what's going on